# Determined number of distinct pairs

Tags: integers

I need help with this question:

Determine the number of distinct pairs $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\times\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ of positive integers satisfying the equation:

$360(a+b)=ab$

For a start, I do observe that ab must be a multiple of 360. But how do I proceed from here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach to the problem.

Rewrite: $ab-360a-360b=0$.

Add something so that the left side can be factored: $ab-360a-360b+360^2=360^2$

Then $(a-360)(b-360)=360^2$.

Go on from there.